# Atom Editor: jupyter-notebook fails to install

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, atom-editor

I use the Atom text editor to write Python. Packages usually install with no problem, but the jupyter-notebook package always fails.

I know I already have Jupyter installed, because it was installed with Anaconda previously.

On Atom, it says:

```
Installing “jupyter-notebook@0.0.9” failed.
```

One thing that I think could be a hint is this text from the output:

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "/Users/(my_name)/anaconda/bin/python" is v3.5.2, which is not supported by gyp.
```

So is my version of Python incompatible? Or maybe I have Jupyter installed in a place where Atom can't access it?

Comment: it seems that that `jupyter-notebook` is no longer mantained, see https://github.com/jupyter/atom-notebook/issues/59